# old inscape version on 17.04

Tags: inkscape

How can I install the old version of Inkscape (0.91) on a new system (17.04 Zesty Zepus)? The system came with the new version (0.92) which I removed via Synaptic and now I don't know how to add the 0.91 one. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Still links for version 0.91 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=inkscape&searchon=names >>> Example http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/inkscape/inkscape_0.91-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb : `cd Downloads/ && sudo gdebi inkscape_0.91-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

Comment: tnx, knud - the same problem as before (the answer was deleted): it reads packages, builds dep tree and all that and then says: this package is not installable. Dependency is not satisfiable: libmagick++-6.q16-5v5. How should I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Inkscape-0.91: You can get a package with a fake name, inkscape_0.92.1-10ubuntu17_amd64.deb → To prevent any automatic update from installing a new version.

`dpkg -s inkscape` will report: Version 0.92.1 ... ... Description: Inkscape 0.91

Download link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNMDVycFMzeGtmLTA/view?usp=sharing The package provides `/usr/local/bin/{inkscape, inkview}`.

The package was compiled and built with Ubuntu 17.04 .

Comment: To prevent updates from overwriting a particular version the proper way is to put a hold (https://askubuntu.com/a/18656/29073) on them, eg `sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>`.